# How to select nth element with certain classname in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

how to select the third element with a certain classname in div in css?

```
<div class=container>
 <div class="hello"><button>Press</button></div>
</div>
<div class=container>
 <div class="hello"><button>Press</button></div>
</div>
<div class=container>
 <div class="hello"><button>Press</button></div>
</div>
```

I want to select the third  or last element with classname "hello".
How to do it?
Please help.

Comment: Yes but nothing realy works

Comment: You can't do `.container .hello:last-child`, you have to start from the parent of .container divs. like: `.parentdiv .container:last-child .hello`